# How to generate `poetry.lock` file for arm64 machine on a x86 machine?

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-3.8, python-poetry

So the, `poetry install` is taking forever to resolve.

On the server as well as on the docker environment, was using `docker buildx`.

So the generic way is to go the pip install way, but that also requires a lock file to be generated.

My server is an arm64 arch machine, whereas my local system is a x86 arch machine.

What could be the best possible way to resolve this?